# sql - sum of orders

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Name      | count
Charlie      10
Charlie       5
Barney        6
Disney        7
```

I was looking to find a sql query which will sum the total for each name and print in descending order of count

Comment: `SELECT SUM(count) FROM mytable GROUP BY Name ORDER BY SUM(count) DESC`

Comment: And what have you tried so far !?

Comment: @shA.t : I tried the following. 
select Name, SUM(count) from mytable ORDER BY DESC SUM(count)

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(count) as total
from tablename
group by Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(count) as Count FROM table 
GROUP BY Name 
ORDER BY SUM(count) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use next query

```
SELECT Name, SUM(count) 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY Name 
ORDER BY SUM(count) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT Name, SUM(count) 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY Name 
ORDER BY SUM(count) DESC
```

In general you can use this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) if you need any help